Command doesn't show put after a new line
I used \newcommand to make a label and then label it.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\createlabel}[2]{%
    \@bsphack
    \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{#2}\@esphack}
    
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\reff}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}

    \begin{document}
    \newcounter{syntes}
    \refstepcounter{syntes}
    
    
    \subsubsection*{Benzyl 5-oxopyrrolidin-2-karboxylát \createlabel{pyro-benz}{\thesyntes} (\reff{pyro-benz})} 
    
    \reff{pyro-benz}

    \end{document}

I'm using the \createlabel in \subsubsection and also the \reff in it, however, when i use it after the line it doesn't show up.
I tried to use \label, however it shows the subsubsection number, however, i need to number my own compounds.
EDIT: after changing \edef to \xdef it started to work. Thanks you @campa

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

In addition to completing your example, could you explain why you're doing this?  You look like you're going to a lot of trouble and some fairly low level commands, and I don't see the consequence.  (There's also no \makeatother.)

You need \xdef instead of \edef but we might be able to suggest better ways if you would explain a bit exactly what you are after.

I'm writing my thesis and i need to give specific compound a number, with which i can refer to it later in text. Normal \label doesn't work.

\label would work but as others have said you need a global definition here as the section heading is a group as it uses local. font settings.

The normal way would be to use \label directly after the \refstepcounter. That would simply work:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcounter{syntes}
\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{syntes}\label{pyro-benz}
    
    
\subsubsection*{Benzyl 5-oxopyrrolidin-2-karboxylát (\ref{pyro-benz})} 
    
\ref{pyro-benz}

\end{document}



To simplify Ulrike's answer, you can make a new command that automates the refstep part:
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\createSyntesLabel}[1]{%
 \refstepcounter{syntes}%
 \label{#1}%
}

\newcounter{syntes}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Benzyl 5-oxopyrrolidin-2-karboxylát\createSyntesLabel{pyro-benz} (\ref{pyro-benz})} 
    
\ref{pyro-benz}

\end{document}

If you're feeling adventurous, you can even make that
\newcommand\createSyntesLabel{\refstepcounter{syntes}\label}
